# Reuse modified key in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
foo = open('words.txt').readlines()
[k.rstrip() for k in foo if k.rstrip() != '']
```

I would like to reuse the *modified key*, like that

```
[k.rstrip() for k in foo if k != '']
```

Is this possible?

---

```
# input (words.txt)
# this will be just some lines with one or more words separated by space. 
# there will be no *special* case or anything 
foo bar  
baz  
bar baz waz

# expected output
>>> ['foo bar', 'baz', 'bar baz waz']
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example what `foo` is.

Comment: You can't really do that.  The target expression of the list comprehension doesn't have access to anything except the iterated item.  You'll have to either make a new iterable based on `foo`, or write out an explicit loop instead of using a list comprehension.

Comment: If you can post some better sample data and expected output then we might be able to suggest better solution if possible.

Comment: @awini-haudhary actually that's the *correct* input, but I'll add an expected output, even when your answer is accepted ;)

Comment: @Lucas But there are not `\n`'s in this data, just in case your data only contains trailing or leading `'\n'` then you can drop the `replace` call.

Comment: @awini-haudhary fair point. I hope this gets now clear from my question (edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
[x for x in (k.replace('\n', '').strip() for k in foo) if x]
```

It looks like you want to filter out empty lines, you can do something like this for that:

```
#Assuming `c` is the file object
>>> [line.rstrip() for line in c if not line.isspace()]
['foo bar', 'baz', 'bar baz waz']
#Demo
>>> foo = ['foo bar\n', 'baz\n', 'bar baz waz\n', '   \n']
>>> [line.strip() for line in foo if not line.isspace()]
['foo bar', 'baz', 'bar baz waz']
```